# Can't use window object until an alert has been sent in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Encountering a slightly weird problem.

I have an array containing ~100 items, each of which is to be an array of its own name. In order to use the variable as the array name, I've been using the `window[VARIABLE_NAME]` approach.

Eg, this is how I initialize them:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array_list.length; i++) {
    window[array_list[i]] = new Array();
}
```

I add data to the arrays and perform some other operations, and at the end I want to sort each array, using a simple custom sort function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array_list.length; i++) {
    var array_name = array_list[i];
    window[array_name].sort(function(a,b) {
        return a[0] - b[0]; 
    }); 
}
```

The problem I'm encountering is that, unless I can do an `alert()` before this for loop, the sort never occurs.

Is there a better approach to this, or do I need to initialize the window object somehow?

All of this is executing within the jQuery `$(document).ready()` function as it is...

Comment: `alert` is a _blocking_ operation, this _really_ sounds like a race condition. Does it work if you wrap it in a `setTimeout` with 10000 miliseconds?

Comment: `I add data to the arrays and perform some other operations` ... AJAX? It would explain why alert helps.

Comment: Might be a good idea to see the rest of your script.  Are you adding data to the arrays from an ajax call or something else asynchronous like that?

Comment: Could you show your full code example?

Comment: Rather than binding directly to window, which many other things are already bound to which makes it confusing, it might be easier to create a namespace on window and bind to that. So you'd use `window.items[VARIABLE_NAME]` instead. This would make it quicker for you to see your results, and less likely to hit a variable name conflict

Comment: Excellent judgement. There was an AJAX call which wasn't finishing and populating the arrays. I adjusted to call the sort into the callback function. Many thanks!

Comment: @Paul Consider adding how you solved the problem as an answer and accepting it. We're glad we helped :)

Comment: You need to show how you add the data as the root of the error is probably related to that part and not the code you're showing here.